I can't install packages after installing glances: "installed glances package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1"
I installed glances via sudo apt-get install -y glances  on Ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Now I can't install packages, e.g.:
dernoncourt@t204-0-0:~$ sudo apt-get install -y nethogs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nethogs is already the newest version (0.8.5-2build2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 126 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up glances (3.1.3-1) ...
groupadd: failure while writing changes to /etc/group
addgroup: `/sbin/groupadd -g 103 glances' returned error code 10. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package glances (--configure):
 installed glances package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 glances
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

How can I fix that?

I unsuccessfully tried:
sudo groupadd glances
sudo apt-get install -y glances
sudo apt-get remove --purge glances
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo dpkg --configure -a

In /etc/:
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      26 Jun  7 04:16 glances
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5410 Jun  7 01:03 group
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5425 Jun  7 04:18 group+
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5410 Jun  7 01:03 group-

/ has 147 GB available.

Why isn’t /etc/group writable? Is your / volume read-only?

or is / 100% full?

@icarus thanks, / has 147 GB available.

@StephenKitt Thanks, /etc/group is writable, see edited question.

OK, diff group group+ should show that the difference is the new glances group. If that is the case, does sudo mv /etc/group+ /etc/group work? If it does, a subsequent sudo dpkg --configure -a should get past the group creation step.
